# Android - retrieving text input from an alertbuilder dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I've got a View defined in an xml file. It contains two Edittext fields (amongt other things like text)

I use an AlertBuilder to trigger a dialog where a user enters text(such as username and pass) into both edittext fields. When I try to retrieve the strings and send them to Login(), both strings are just null. What is going on?

It seems like somehow the string data isn't saved?

Here's when I show the Dialog in my app:

```
SignInDialog.show(ScreenMain.this, 
                                "Login", 
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ScreenMain.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_dialog_login, null);
                                        LogIn(((EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.screen_dialog_login_username_edit)).getText().toString(),
                                                        ((EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.screen_dialog_login_password_edit)).getText().toString());

                                    }
                                }, 
                                "Cancel", 
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
```

Here's a class I use to instantiate a Dialog:

```
/* login dialog*/
static class SignInDialog {

    public static void show(Context context, String positiveText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positive, String negativeText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negative){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_dialog_login, null);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(layout);
        if(positive != null && positiveText != null){
            builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, positive);
        }
        if(negative != null && negativeText != null){
            builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, negative);
        }

        builder.create().show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inflate a layout is to create a new instance of it. (You're not receiving a reference to an existing instance.)  So, in your `onClick` you are creating a new copy of the layout and your fields don't contain any text because they are not the same ones your user just entered text in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just completely subclass `AlertDialog.Builder` and add a method to retrieve the `EditText` values?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_dialog_login, null);

layout.findViewById(R.id.*yourwidget*);
```

i tried it and it helped

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I am using:

```
private void showPopUp3() {          

                 AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmReceiverActivity.this);
                 helpBuilder.setTitle("hi");
                // helpBuilder.setMessage(&quot;This is a Simple Pop Up&quot;);
                 final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                 input.setHeight(20);
                 input.setText("");
                 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                 final View checkboxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm, null);


                 checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.Yes).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // setTitle("button2");
                            checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.note).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                 checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.No).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // setTitle("button2");
                            checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.note).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                 helpBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);

                 helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("No",
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     // Do nothing but close the dialog
                         mMediaPlayer.stop();
                         finish();
                    }
                   });
                 helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
                           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             // Do nothing but close the dialog
                     mMediaPlayer.stop();

                        //showSimplePopUp();

                            }
                           });
                 // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
                 AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                 helpDialog.show();
            }
```